# How can I find the best possible shift to correlate two data sets in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

In Python, I have a two-dimensional data set consisting of the two lists, `x1` and `y1`. I also have another set, `x2` and `y2`, defined as follows:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the real shift
shift = 50.5

# Fluctuation of single data points
f = 1

# Fraction of missing points or extra points
a = 0.02

data1_x = []
data1_y = []
data2_x = []
data2_y = []
for index in range(int(shift)):
    data2_x.append(index + f*random.random())
    data2_y.append(0 + f*random.random())

for index in range(500):
    x = index
    if index<100:
        y = 0
    elif index<200:
        y = (index-100)
    elif index<300:
        y = 100
    elif index<400:
        y = 400 - index
    else:
        y = 0

    if random.random()>a:
        data1_x.append(x + f*random.random())
        data1_y.append(y + f*random.random())
    if random.random()>a:
        data2_x.append(x + shift + f*random.random())
        data2_y.append(y + f*random.random())

    if random.random()<a:
        data1_x.append(x + 0.5 + f*random.random())
        data1_y.append(100 * random.random())
    if random.random()<a:
        data2_x.append(x + shift + 0.5 + f*random.random())
        data2_y.append(100 * random.random())


# Calculation
view = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view
n = len(data1_x)
idx = ((view(data2_y, n) - np.array(data1_y))**2).sum(1).argmin()
calculated_shift = np.polyfit(data1_x, data2_x[idx:n+idx], 1)[1]
print(f"calculated shift: {calculated_shift}")

# Plot the original and shifted signals along with cross-correlation
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.scatter(data1_x, data1_y, s=20, marker="o", c="b", label="Data1")
plt.scatter(data2_x, data2_y, s=5, marker="o", c="g", label="Data2")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.scatter(data1_x, data1_y, s=20, marker="o", c="b", label="Data1")
plt.scatter([x-calculated_shift for x in data2_x], data2_y, s=5, marker="o", c="g", label="Data2")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The real-world data

- might have different lengths (as the example)
- the x-values (time) might not be equidistant (as the example)
- a point in a dataset might not have a corresponding point in the other data set (as the example)
- the y values might not be exactly the same (as the example)

Given the solution from Onyambu I get e.g. the following result:

[image]

The above image show the original data and the plot below shows the data shifted back. It is obvious there is a significant discrepancy still left!

How to improve the calculation so the points will really on top of each other?

Comment: Here you have exactly the same shift for all points, is this the case in real-life?

Comment: Yes, in the real-life case I assume to have the same shift for all points.

Comment: Then simply `x2[0]-x1[0]`? Assuming `y2 = y1` as shown. If not, please update the example.

Comment: In reality the two data sets might have different number of entries

Comment: The please update your example to reflect this. The current example is too trivial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256686/discussion-between-alex-and-mozway).

Comment: You've added a description, but the example is the old one. You could add some noise and such to the original example, to give a better idea of real-world data.

Comment: sure, I can add some randomness

Comment: Your graphs indicate that you need to fit a piecewise model and not a simple linear model

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
import numpy as np
view = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view

n = len(x1)
idx = ((view(y2, n) - np.array(y1))**2).sum(1).argmin()
np.polyfit(x1, x2[idx:n+idx], 1)
array([0.99860253, 2.28108306]) # close to [1, 2.273]
```

Comment: for some reasons does not work for real data

Comment: @Alex you will have to include a batch of real data. The logic given is simple. If the arrays are huge then better use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to determine the starting point of y1 in y2. You could also use EM algorithm. Any of those should give you the starting index. from which you can directly extract your y2 and fit a linear model to determine your coefficients. In worst case scenario, fit a segmented model, with at most 2 breaks

Comment: How to share some data?

Comment: Seems I cannot share real data. Would you be available for a lecture in python data science?

Comment: @Alex, You do not need to share irl real data: Manipulate portion of the data that you have and share that. ie multiply with constant, add a constant. etc. Plot your data, check where the break points occur. Select a few points in each segment and share those.  Check out [segmented regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression#:~:text=Segmented%20regression%2C%20also%20known%20as,is%20fit%20to%20each%20interval.) If you want tutoring, you will have to pay.

Comment: I have created an example that clearly shows your suggestion might not work in noisy data. You can clearly see the re-shifted plots do not lie on top of each other ...

Comment: I also tried to  use your suggestion `scipy.optimize.minimize` but so far it always returns the initial guess, so I think I have to write my own optimizer function.

Comment: @Alex at no point should it return the initial results. It always works, unless you have a ill-defined function

Comment: Ok, let me prove it. I will create another post with another set of some test data.

Comment: Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77898398/why-does-scipy-optimize-minimize-always-return-the-initial-value

Comment: The actual real data is much more complicated than thought. I will be  more complicated to create fake data than to just use real data ...