# Why does `scipy.optimize.minimize` always return the initial value?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a complete working code that uses `scipy.optimize.minimize` but always returns  the initial value as the optimized scalar parameter. Here is the complete code:

```
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

# Define the real shift
shift = 50.5

data1_x = []
data1_y = []
data2_x = []
data2_y = []
for index in range(int(shift)):
    data2_x.append(index)
    data2_y.append(0)

for index in range(500):
    x = index
    if index<100:
        y = 0
    elif index<200:
        y = (index-100)
    elif index<300:
        y = 100
    elif index<400:
        y = 400 - index
    else:
        y = 0

    data1_x.append(x)
    data1_y.append(y)
    data2_x.append(x + shift)
    data2_y.append(y)

index_range = range(len(data2_x))

# The function to minimize, returning a float
def overlap(shift, data1_x, data1_y, data2_x, data2_y):
    sum_ = 0
    for index1 in range(len(data1_x)):
        x1 = data1_x[index1] + shift[0]
        index2 = min(index_range, key=lambda i: abs(data2_x[i]-x1))
        x2 = data2_x[index2]
        y1 = data1_y[index1]
        y2 = data2_y[index2]

        # Ignore x values outside of common range
        if abs(x2-x1)>5:
            continue
        sum_ += abs(y2 - y1)
        
    return sum_

# Here chose some other initial value instead of '40'.
result = opt.minimize(overlap, 40, args=(data1_x, data1_y, data2_x, data2_y))

# Print message indicating why the process terminated
print(result.message)

# Print the minimum value of the function
print(result.fun)

# Print the x-value resulting in the minimum value
print(result.x)
calculated_shift = result.x[0]

# Plot the original and shifted signals along with cross-correlation
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.scatter(data1_x, data1_y, s=20, marker="o", c="b", label="Data1")
plt.scatter(data2_x, data2_y, s=5, marker="o", c="g", label="Data2")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.scatter(data1_x, data1_y, s=20, marker="o", c="b", label="Data1")
plt.scatter([x-calculated_shift for x in data2_x], data2_y, s=5, marker="o", c="g", label="Data2")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Why does `optimize` not optimize?

Comment: Seems the question as changed abit. Is the parameter of interest just the shift? Nothing more? Also is the shift universal to all the datapoints that were shifted? ie just one value to all of the points?

Comment: The parameter `shift` is the only single scalar float value that is supposed to get optimized. And as you can see from the code example, that constant float value affects EVERY x value for dataset1.

Comment: Test it  first with some trivial function with a clear maximum like a quadratic to establish that you are using it correctly. It is just possible that your function is already at a local minimum in which case it will return the initial guess. But my money is on there being something fundamentally wrong with your "overlap" function. Can you explain what it is intending to do?

Comment: I have an example that shows that the `minimize` method of scipy does not work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Onyambu I can explain what I actually want to do here. Based on  the other question this `overlap` function returns a kind of the overlap between the two datasets given a shift-value. Ideal overlap means you get zero in return

Comment: Your code seems to work on my end: `opt.minimize_scalar(overlap, ([0],[20]), args=(data1_x, data1_y, data2_x, data2_y))`

Comment: Ah interesting, I need to checkout this `minimize_scalar` function...

Comment: But when using this with fake data containing random values the result of this optimization is complete nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minimize()` assumes that the function it is optimizing is differentiable. This function is not differentiable.

You can see this by adding a print statement right before the end of your function.

```
print(f"{shift[0]=} {sum_=}")
return sum_
```

When optimizing, this prints the following.

```
shift[0]=40.33661619031734 sum_=2000
shift[0]=40.336616205218505 sum_=2000
```

It gives two inputs which differ by 10^-8, and gets back exactly the same result. Therefore, it concludes that the function is flat around this point.

There are three things you can try in this situation:

1. Rewrite the function to be differentiable, so that when it gets slightly closer to the right answer, the return value gets slightly smaller.
2. Use brute force. Since only integer changes in the function change the output, you could write a program that loops over all integers that the shift could be, and try all of them.
3. Use an optimizer that doesn't require the function to be differentiable.
4. `minimize()` can be forced to take larger steps when differentiating through the `eps` option. I also found it was necessary to change from BFGS to L-BFGS-B.

   This can find a shift value of ~50.

   ```
   result = opt.minimize(overlap, 40, args=(data1_x, data1_y, data2_x, data2_y), options={'eps': 1}, method='L-BFGS-B')
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am not looking for an integer as solution. The solution is a FLOAT, in the given example it is the value 50.5.

Comment: But you are right, the overlap function does not seem to be differentiable. Then I understand why this is not working. Thanks. Question solved.

Comment: @Alex If the solution 50.5 gives the exact same result as 50.1 or 51.0, I don't see how minimize() could know that 50.5 is the right answer.

Comment: There is a small bug in the overlap function...